Create OVS queues and assign them to already created queues with TC
I am using OVS and Mininet for some experiments. When adding links with mininet, using bw. max_queue_size params, and other link related configs is actually using TC under the hood.
Now I am adding a small modification to the code be able to add sub-queues with TC for the parent queue when controlling the bandwidth.
cmds += [
    f"tc class add dev %s parent 5:1 classid 5:10 htb rate {bw // 2}Mbit ceil {bw} prio 7",  # default
    f"tc class add dev %s parent 5:1 classid 5:20 htb rate {bw bw //4}Mbit ceil {bw} prio 1",  # high prio
    "tc qdisc add dev %s parent 5:10 handle 10: htb",
    "tc qdisc add dev %s parent 5:20 handle 20: htb",
]

Code for creating the parent Queue

cmds += [ 'tc qdisc add dev %s root handle 5:0 htb default 10',
          f'tc class add dev %s parent 5:0 classid 5:1 htb rate {bw}Mbit burst 15k']

Now, after creationg these two sub-queues, I want to attach them with OVS queues.
The only way I found is
cmd = (f"ovs-vsctl -- set port %s qos=@newqos "
       f"-- --id=@newqos create qos type=linux-htb other-config:max-rate={max_rate} queues=10=@q0,20=@q1 "
       f"-- --id=@q0 create queue other-config:min-rate={min_rate} other-config:max-rate={max_rate} other_config:priority=7 "
       f"-- --id=@q1 create queue other-config:min-rate={min_rate} other-config:max-rate={max_rate} other_config:priority=1")

The OVS command itself uses TC under the hood which overrides the originial created queues for the interface.
Any suggestion to create Queues in OVS but use the already-created Queues with TC?
Thanks
